# Is a signer required to have a DocuSign account to sign a document?

Tags: docusignapi

1. It seems like a signer has to create or already have a DocuSign account in order to electronically sign a document? Is that true?
2. If I'm having users sign the document on my app, do I need to supply the API with a signer? Meaning, does the envelope have to set recipients/signers?  I may not know who (name, email, etc) is signing the document. I'm finding that my code (C#) has to do something like this (attached), and I don't understand if it's required:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, signers do not need an account themselves to sign.  With DocuSign only SENDERS or those who CREATE the signature request need an account do so (in other words, you need an account to create `Envelopes`) however signers don't need an account and signing is always free.

You can create a free developer sandbox (which operates in the DocuSign Demo environment) and send test signature requests to any recipients you'd like.

[DocuSign Dev Center](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center)